# Python scraping website with flight tickets

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am trying to extract information about prices of flight tickets with a python script. Please take a look at the picture:

[image: Inspect element]

I would like to parse all the prices (such as "121" at the bottom of the tree). I have constructed a simple script and my problem is that I am not sure how to get the right parts from the code behind page's "inspect element". My code is below:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

http = urllib3.PoolManager()


ULR = "https://greatescape.co/?datesType=oneway&dateRangeType=exact&departDate=2019-08-19&origin=EAP&originType=city&continent=europe&flightType=3&city=WAW"
response = http.request('GET', URL)
soup = BS(response.data, "html.parser")

body = soup.find('body')
__next = body.find('div', {'id':'__next'})
ui_container = __next.find('div', {'class':'ui-container'})
bottom_container_root = ui_container.find('div', {'class':'bottom-container-root'})

print(bottom_container_root)
```

The problem is that I am stuck at the level of `ui-container`. `bottom-container-root` is an empty variable, despite it is a direct child under `ui-container`. Could someone please let me know how to parse this tree properly?

I have no experience in web scraping, but as it happens it is one step in a bigger workflow I am building.

Comment: content is added dynamically from a series of API calls looking for results from various partners. You will need to see if there is logic you can replicate and whether this is ok within T&C.

Answer (score 0):

`.find_next_siblings` and `.next_element` can be useful in navigating through containers.

Here is some example usage below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = open("small.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.head.next_element
print soup.head.next_element.next_element
```

Comment: Is there  any way to after scrap data from website can book a flight?. Website have login system after login i can get a data but next step is to want to book through beautifulsoup  or any other lib?